# Move or not pg_catalog schema to new database

Tags: postgresql

I want to move schemas and data of my current Postgres 11 database to a new Postgres 13 database.

I do `pg_dump` for that purpose to firstly dump to files schemas, data etc. I am not sure about whether should i also take `pg_catalog` schema. Can someone advice?

Comment: no. thats a system/database schema. Your new database will have one. Only move the information you want to keep/created yourself.

Comment: @VynlJunkie so only the schemas that have been created by me, i understand, thank you in advance. P.S Just additionally can u tell me whether versions of postgres (as i migrate from 11 to 13) somehow could impact on such process i am doing with pg_dump then with loading all of that to 13' ?

Comment: pg_dump should be good for re-runnable sql between versions, however, there are always potential breaking changes between major versions. Always check the release notes. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/release/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pg_catalog` contains the database metadata. When you export a database, you do not directly export data from these tables. They get exported implicitly in the shape of the `CREATE` and `ALTER` statements that `pg_dump` generates.

`pg_dump` will export all data from a database (but it excludes the definition of users and tablespaces and permissions on the database).